# bootstrap dropdown menu always showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The code:

```
<nav class='secondary-nav container'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Customer Care</a></li>
    <li class='dropdown'>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home
      <b class='caret'></b>
      </a>
      <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Google</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/sign_out">Sign Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have jQuery, bootstrap-dropdown.js, and bootstrap.css incuded. jQuery is included before everything.

The dropdown menu is appearing by default before a mouse click or hover on the list element.

screenshot - http://cl.ly/image/41122D2Z3R38

Anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: pls post css or jsfiddle .......

Comment: I have created [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8VZz/), but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing without your css code we can not understand your problem.
But as I can see, you `data` attribute is correctly used, but are you linking you `javascript` files correctly?

```
"bootsrtap.js" and "Your jquery File"
```

The second thing look out on your javascript applying code.
The applying code of the nav menu of bootsrtap is :

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

try to revise your file codes and I think this will help you ^_^